# How to use a string[ ] list in a nested Select statement in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, subquery, sql-in

Passing **string[] list** to retrieve data from db using an **IN** operator.

`Select col1, col2, col3 from tablename where col4 IN (// the list goes here);`

The number of items in the list can exceed to 1000 and since Oracle doesn't allow to pass more than 1000 expressions in a list, I'm looking for an alternative. Now the issues:

1: I don't want to create a temporary table in DB because I don't have enough privileges.

2: Not sure if multiple INs would work cause the list is dynamic and requirement of no. of **IN** operator could change

So here's something I wanna do but don't know how:

`SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tablename where col4 IN (Select col4 from "string[]list";)`

Is there a way to use this *list* in the nested select statement ?
OR any other alternative to use more than 1000 expressions while giving respect to above mentioned issues ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

P.S. I have simplified the query to give an idea to people, willing to help. The original query is much more than this!

**UPDATE**

So after @Barry O'Kane showed me a way to work around this, I came up with the following solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> List = arrExcelItems; //arrExcelItems is the actual list with more than 1000 expressions
IList<IEnumerable<string>> listofLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
    List<string> listtoQuery = new List<string>();
    string strCompList = null;
    string extQuery = null;


    string extQuery = null; string Query = "Select col1, col2, col3 from tablename where col4 IN ";

                for (int i = 0; i < List.Count(); i += 20)
                {
                    listofLists.Add(List.Skip(i).Take(20).ToList()); //Adding every 20 items of list to the listoflists[i] index 

                    for (int j = 0; j < listofLists.Count; j++) //possibility of improving OR removing this for loop and use only string.Join method.
                    {
                        strCompList = string.Join("','", listofLists[j].ToArray()); 
                    }

                    strCompList = "('" + strCompList + "')"; //concatenating every list in listofLists[i] for IN operator

                    arrList.Add(strCompList);
                }

    for (int i = 0; i < listtoQuery.Count; i++)
            {
                   extquery = string.Join(" OR IN ", listtoQuery);  //                       
            }

            Query += extQuery;

    //resultant query after concatenation

    Query = "Select col1, col2, col3 from tablename where col4 IN listtoQuery[0] OR col4 IN listtoquery[1] OR col4 IN....";
```

So finally I found out a solution where I can partition my list into *multiple lists* and passing them each to *multiple **IN** operators*. I hope it could be useful for others. 
**Note:** I'm open to suggestions and improvements since I am very new to programming world.

Comment: if there are more than 1K search values, split them in batches of 1k values and run the query several times (with each batch)?

Comment: @ASh The problem is, it's not just a query but queries to get sets of information from the db. It's already quite complex and I don't wanna compromise on the performance by re-running queries. But I guess that's the only possible solution so far. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets assume you have an `IList<int> items` with 2300 items in it.

Since 1000 items is the limit lets break it down and loop it like that

```
DataTable dt;
int iterator = items.Count / 1000;
int remainder = items.Count % 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < iterator; i++)
{
    if (i ==0)
        dt = new DataTable();

    //Get 1000 items for the in clause
    var inStr = string.Join(items.Take(1000).skip(i*1000).ToArray(),',');
    // Build the sql query
    var query = string.Format("Select col1, col2, col3 from tablename where col4 IN ({0})", inStr);
    // Execute the query and add the items to the data table
    dt.Merge(// DataTable from the query);
}

var finalIn = string.Join(items.Take(remainder).Skip(iterator*1000).ToArray(), ',');
// Build and execute the query for the final time and add to dt again
dt.Merge(// DataTable from the query);
```

If you have strings or something else then amend the code as necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Barry O'Kane I'm trying to use your idea but rather implementing it with **IEnumerable<T>**. If I don't find a desired solution I'd have to stick with this.

Comment: An alternative as long as T inherits from object, would be to add parameters for each item in the `IN` clause and append the parameter string to `inStr`. Let me know if you want the answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: I have updated my post with my own solution. Have a look and feel free to criticize :)